# Data structure for arguments in Arrow functions in JS

Tags: data-structures, memory-allocation, generating-functions

As per the rules of JS, `Arrow` functions don't have an *argument Object*, like a regular function inside JS.
But it is also true, that we can pass arguments to the `Arrow` functions like any other functions.
What is the data structure at play here, if not an argument object, then how does an `Arrow` functions references the arguments passed down to it ?

Comment: Coding questions and questions specific to individual programming languages (like Javascript) are off-topic here.  I don't know what an Arrow function is.  I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Its more of a JS architecture question. These are another way of declaring functions, the difference lies in the execution context of these functions and how memory is allocated.

Comment: Question is off-topic as it regards a coding issue

Comment: Why would there be any difference?